# How to use query parameters with Exo Player?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm using exo player to play streams but if I pass the query parameters like below exo player giving the following error:

> https://abcdefgh.mp4?a=2RC2ozysgsyzkLsdfksI_g&b=159868763671

```
com.google.android.exoplayer2.ParserException: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unterminated entity ref (position:TEXT @6:26 in java.io.InputStreamReader@bc02e5a)
```

How can I apply the query parameters to Exo Player source ?

Comment: Hi Could you find a solution.. i have this kind of query parameter "https://bla_bla.com/test.m3u8?media-auth=exp=edef~acl=/msng/cdc-cd32/*~hmac=njjcnd3902 " ?